# How come Orwell's 1984 and North Korea are so similar?

Tags: north-korea

Is it just a coincidence that Orwell published the book 1984 in June 1949 and North Korea was founded in September 1948?

I'm watching documentaries about North Korea and I'm shook by the similarities, it's like I'm watching a movie made out of the book 1984. The constant surveillance, the daily shows in summertime that are pure propaganda, the rituals etc. - it just looks the same to me and surreal.

Comment: All of the things you describe were present in the USSR in the 1930s and also Nazi Germany. NK is just unusually stable and frozen at that time period.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it just a coincidence that Orwell published the book 1984 in June 1949 and North Korea was founded in September 1948?

Possibly.

Orwell began writing the book in 1947, and [it has been suggested](https://web.archive.org/web/20110829021052/http://gseis.ucla.edu/faculty/kellner/essays/from1984toonedimensional.pdf) that Orwell's vision of the totalitarian Oceania was inspired by the USSR, with Big Brother representing Josef Stalin. Korea had already been divided by then, with the USSR occupying the north of the country after World War II, and the US occupying the south. It was only after attempts to unite the two halves failed that they split into separate nations: the US-backed South Korea and the USSR-backed North Korea.

Orwell was not inspired by North Korea, and North Korea was obviously not inspired by *Nineteen Eighty-Four*, but it's possible they *were* both inspired by the same thing: the USSR.

Comment: Yup.  Add to that that [Animal Farm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Farm)  was definitely Stalin-sourced.  I think that it's just that Orwell was a singularly prescient and clever guy, with quite wide life experiences, and his *dictator's handbook* is so close because it **is** a good way to leverage the resources of a modern state to achieve total control, as demonstrated by Uncle Joe.  Most countries stop short of NK's taking it to the extremes, but you see all sorts of glimmers of 1984 in many badly-governed countries.

Answer (score 3):

1984 was a literary depiction of full-scale totalitarian regime: a regime that imposes itself on the public at all levels, through intense surveillance, pervasive propaganda, and brutal repression of everything that might in any way question or conflict with the authority, power, and messaging of the ruling group. Full control is the natural aspiration of totalitarianism, and any regime that leans that way is going to mirror aspects of the novel. Orwell wasn't trying to depict any particular (extant) government; he was trying to demonstrate the outcome of a particular political tendency. It wasn't coincidence or imitation; it was more like Orwell was writing a natural history of an observable phenomenon.